Wagtail django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1463, "Non-grouping field 'numchild' is used in HAVING clause")
I'm working on a Django project and I've encountered an issue that I'm unable to resolve. When I try to run my application, I get the following error:
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1463, "Non-grouping field 'numchild' is used in HAVING clause")

I'm not sure what's causing this error. I'm not explicitly using a HAVING clause in my queries, and 'numchild' is a field that's managed by Django's** Wagtail** module, not something I've added myself.
I'm using the following packages:
wagtail>=5.0 mysqlclient==2.2.4
Every things working fine locally using sqlite.
I tried to downgrade my mysqlclient version from 2.2.4 to 2. Without sucess. I would like to have the result as sqlite.

Hmmm I am surprised SQlite will let you get away with that. MySQL used to but finally fixed that in 5.7.
Anyway, we need to see the query that is throwing that error to have any hope of helping you correct it.

i'm using Maridb 11.3.2.
